# Selenium Executing JavaScript within the page

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am using Selenium 2 and I need to execute some JavaScript in the page as part of the tests.
I saw various examples on the web, no one of them seem to work.

What I need to do it's this: after the user interacts with the web page, pressing buttons, adding text etc, I need to get the user selection, which is raw javascript is:

```
public void jsTest() {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("http://www.tinymce.com/");
    WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));

    driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);

    WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body"));
    body.sendKeys("Write something");
    JavascriptExecutor js;
    js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    Object o = js.executeScript("return document.querySelector('iframe')");
    System.out.println("o = " + o);


    driver.close();
    driver.quit();

}
```

The result of this code is always that `document.querySelector` is undefined.

Alternatively I also tried passing a second argument to `js.executeScript`:

```
public void jsTest() {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("http://www.tinymce.com/");
    WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));

    driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);

    WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body"));
    body.sendKeys("Write something");
    JavascriptExecutor js;
    js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    Object o = js.executeScript("return arguments[0].querySelector('iframe')", iframe);
    System.out.println("o = " + o);


    driver.close();
    driver.quit();

}
```

And in this case I get: org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element belongs to a different frame than the current one - switch to its containing frame to use it

I also found that it was possible to use BrowserBot: `this.browserbot.getUserWindow()` or `selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow()` but it doesn't seem to work anymore.

The reason I am doing this it's that I need to get the user selection while typing, for example cursor position, and this is possible in plain JavaScript with: `document.getSelection()`. I can consider alternative ways to get the same result.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you try returning the iframe object before switching to the iframe?

Comment: if I move `driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);` just before of `driver.close()` I get an empty list. Changing the selector to this: `Object o = js.executeScript("return arguments[0].querySelectorAll('*')", body);` Object o is made of a number of elements like `o = [[org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement@5d21e41 -> unknown locator]]`

Comment: What I meant is move "Object o = js.executeScript("return document.querySelector('iframe')");" before driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);

Comment: yes that's what I did, and in that case I just get an empty list. `o = []`

Comment: Can you try Object o = js.executeScript("return document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]");

Comment: In this case I get `o = [org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement@120f4a47 -> unknown locator]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56244/discussion-between-maurizio-and-purus).

Comment: Why on earth are you running `document.QuerySelector` directly

Comment: Because I need to get the selection into the iframe to "see" where the caret is located in the editor. The full command I need to run will be: `document.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.document.getSelection()`. Is there a way to run this directly within selenium?