# Selenium web driver use with iframe and conteneditable

Tags: javascript, iframe, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am looking for a way to test content editable and user interactions, to test for example when the user does some actions like deleting, moving, selecting the document.
My first approach has been to try running JavaScript in the page ( see this other question of mine: [Selenium Executing JavaScript within the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24399302/selenium-executing-javascript-within-the-page) ) But probably I am taking the wrong approach.

Is there in selenium any native way to deal with those components? For example once I select the right components in the page I am able to send keystrokes, but then how can I check the html within the page or the cursor position?

For example once the page is loaded I would have an html like this:

```
<body>
    <div>Page content...</div>
    <iframe>
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body contenteditbale="true">
                Here is where the user is interacting.
            </body>
        </html>
    </iframe>
</body>
```

Selenium would interact with the body within the iframe doing actions. To get the position of the cursor, the selection etc, in JavaScript I do: `document.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.document.getSelection();`. I would like to do the same, or have an alternative method to do so.

Comment: How does `iframe` relate to any of this? Do you have an actual example, or are you looking for a speculative discussion?

Comment: I added few more details to the question,so it's better understandable.

Comment: Are you talking about TinyMCE editor? Have you seen [this](http://yizeng.me/2014/01/31/test-wysiwyg-editors-using-selenium-webdriver/)? Have a search on "tinymce selenium" and you will find more examples.

Comment: Thanks @YiZeng I saw that example and I used it to write some code. If you have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24399302/selenium-executing-javascript-within-the-page you will see what I was trying to do before.

Comment: I do am testing TinyMCE

Comment: I don't work for TinyMCE but I work for another company called ephox, and we take care of the enterprise support for it. The reason we want to introduce this kind of testing is because of browser inconsistencies when it comes to actions like pressing backspace, or copy and pasting content from different sources. The only way to make it reliable, without faking events, which leads to even more problems, is to use solutions like Selenium which take care of browser interactions.